# How to add an image slider for each react bootsrap card in a Card Deck

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

After reading the official `react-bootstrap` documentation I have not found any example or seen it anywhere.

I found examples of how to move the card elements in a carousel, but it is not what I am looking for.

What I need is that for each card, instead of showing a single static image, show a series of images that can slide like a carousel. (If possible, with carousel navigation controls show only on hover).

How could I get something like this (Airbnb example):

[image]

[Using the react component - Card Deck](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/#card-deck)

Comment: you can put carousel instead of image in card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### HTML Solution

I simply added `carousel code` instead of `image`. I code into simple HTML

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random=1" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random=2" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random=3" alt="image">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators1" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random=4" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random=5" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random=6" alt="image">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators3" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators3" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators3" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random=7" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random=8" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?random=9" alt="image">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators3" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators3" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

#### React Solution

Here is the link where you can find `react-solution`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3pzcic

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had in mind to do something like this, but I'm new in React and I am a little bit confused with components.

Do you know how to do exactly this in react?

Comment: make a carousel component in React and pass an array of images and carousel id as props, so no duplication

Comment: I already have a carousel component in React, which I use in another section of the webpage. I don't think I'm following you, could you provide an example?

Comment: I added `react-solution`, watch out

Comment: Thank you so much! That is what I was looking for!